# Why isn't my if/else statment working in my range? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, range

```
start = int(input("Enter your starting value "))
end = int(input("Enter your ending value "))
inc = int(input("Enter your increment value "))

inc = int(input("Enter your increment value "))
for j in range (start,end,inc):
    if start > end:
        print("Nothing to show here!")
    else:
        print(j)
```

Instead of outputting "Nothing to show here!" as it should, it just outputs the end value instead. It works perfectly fine otherwise, but I want to know why it doesn't output my quote.

Comment: `start` will never be greater than `end`

Comment: What are the values of `start` and `end`? If `start` is not larger than `end` then the condition is false.

Comment: That's not true @blorgon. Python will happily iterate backward with a negative `inc`.

Comment: They're variables, I just added that part of the code. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Mark not if `start < end` lol.

Comment: @CosmicSaturn adding the variables as `inputs` is not helpful since we don't know what you are inputing. Add the actual values that cause the problem you are seeing. The idea is to allow others to _reproduce_ the problem you are having.

Comment: im inputing 12 for start and 11 for end

Comment: `start` can only be greater than `end` if you also use a negative increment. Please include the values entered. Better yet, just hard code `start`, `end` and `inc` that cause the problem so that the program runs without user input.

Answer (score 5):

If `start` is greater than `end` (and `inc` is positive), the `range` itself is empty; the loop never runs, so the test is never performed and the `print` doesn't happen. If you want a test like this, it needs to be *outside* the loop, e.g.:

```
if start > end:
    print("Nothing to show here!")
else:
    for j in range(start,end,inc):
        print(j)
```

Technically, this is wrong when `inc` is negative (there would be things to show when `start > end`); if you need to handle that (in some cases you may know `inc` will always be `>= 1`), I'd probably just simplify to:

```
rng = range(start,end,inc)
if not rng:  # Test if the range is empty
    print("Nothing to show here!")
else:
    for j in rng:  # Iterate non-empty range
        print(j)
```

Comment: I like the second part of the answer.

Comment: @DYZ: Yeah, when `range` will tell you if it's empty or not, best to let it do the work for you rather than reimplementing the tests and risking getting something wrong. Same reason you test if a `str` represents a valid `int` by just calling `int()` on it and handling the exception, rather than using `str.isdigit` and company that will miss corner cases (e.g. leading `-`, leading or trailing whitespace, etc.).

Comment: The top part of the answer helped me, thank you!

Comment: @CosmicSaturn - if the first part works for you, you may want to validate `inc` also. Perhaps `if start > end or inc <= 0:` which would also stop a negative incrment.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `start` will never be larger than `end`, even if the increment exceeds the value of `end`.

For example:

```py
for i in range(1, 10, 100):
    print(i)
```

This code block will only run once and print the number 1.
This happens because a for loop does 3 things.

First, it assigns the current index to the variable given. So it executes `i = 1`
Second, it checks if `i < 10`. In the first iteration, that is true. So it prints `1`
And third, it increments `i`. This means that after that iteration it executes `i = 1 + 100`

The third step in the next iterations overshadows the first step.
That means that the assignment doesn't happen and that the incrementation is executed.

The other reason that this doesn't work, is because the `end` argument of `range` is exclusive. This means that the check the for loop makes in the second step is not a `<=` but a `<`. So even if the increment is 1, `start` will never have the same value of `end`

Comment: Not true if `inc` is negative.

Comment: You are right, but that means that again `start` will never be equal to `end`.